# Unable to delete empty rows from Excel file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I am trying to delete empty rows from my Excel.

I have tried seeing other examples and even tried implementing but it doesn't work.What I need to do is delete an entire row If the first cell of that row is empty.

Here is what I have tried:

ReadExcel.cs:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation)
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
int rowCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
      if (usedRange.Cells[1, 1] == null)
             {
                // Delete entire row if first cell is empty
                usedRange.Cells[1, 1]).EntireRow.Delete(null);
            }

            workbook.Save();
        }
```

The problem that I face is that it keeps on looping through the excel and does not follow the if condition even when the cell is null

Comment: `usedRange.Cells[1, 1]` (2 occurrences)
Here it seems you should use your `i` variable instead of one of the `1`, otherwise you will always be testing the line and column index 1 instead of checking each line.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if indexes are 0 based or 1 based in excel. But in C# first element of an array is index 0.

Comment: Hi @Pac0 thanks for pointing that out, corrected! Still doesn't work though..

Answer (score 2):

First you code is always deleting row 1.  You should be moving through all the rows.  Second whenever deleting always start at the end and move towards the beginning otherwise you can miss rows.  The issue is if you delete row 4 then row 5 becomes 4 and you skip row 5.  See code below

```
        for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
             if (usedRange.Cells[i, 1] == null)
             {
                // Delete entire row if first cell is empty
                usedRange.Cells[i, 1]).EntireRow.Delete(null);
             }

        }
        workbook.Save();
```

Comment: Hi @jdweng , thanks for the answer. I tried this but when I debug I noticed that according to the condition if the cell is empty it should hit the code "usedRange.Cells[i, 1]).EntireRow.Delete(null);"  but it doesn't , from if(usedRange.Cells[i, 1] == null), it jumps straight to workbook.Save( ) :-(

Comment: I don't think you need usedRange.  Just checking the cell should work.  I also just noticed the i >= 0 should be i >= 1 since rows and columns in excel start at 1.

Comment: instead of usedRange.Cells[i, 1] == null, I used worksheet.Cells[i, 1] == null, and I also changed to i>=1, still doesn't delete, it simply doesn't execute this line usedRange.Cells[i, 1]).EntireRow.Delete(null);..what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same fix that you made : worksheet.Cells[i, 1].EntireRow.Delete;  Not sure what (null) is doing.  I suspect it is replacing the row with null instead of deleting.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention I had removed null...even after that what I noticed was  the excel that I read has data only in first five rows i.e the row count is 28 of which only 5 rows have data, but still the condition is false for all the 28 rows. Shouldn't the condition be false only for the first 5 rows and true for the last 23 rows?..these are the ones I need to delete...

Comment: Also, isn't usedRange suppose to read only the rows/columns that have data or that had data? I

Comment: Excel doesn't actually remove rows from the middle.  Just removes from the list of used cells.  I often have issues trying to make an excel file smaller.  The only real way is to copy data into a new workbook. Excel is really a front end application that uses Jet/Ace as the back end driver to access the file.  Deleting data in the middle of a file takes time because you have to take everything after the removed data and move it.  To make excel fast the compression is automatic to remove unused items, and not all unused items get removed.  So UsedRange may falsely detect empty rows/columns.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng , just changed to this: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((worksheet.Cells[i, 1]).Text.ToString())).. works fine :-)

Comment: yes !! When I tried earlier it didn't work for some reason, but now I checked once again it does :-)

Comment: Value2 is more efficient than Text.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works:

```
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = usedRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = usedRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = rowCount; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((worksheet.Cells[i, 1]).Text.ToString()))
            {
                // Delete entire row if first cell is empty
                (worksheet.Cells[i, 1]).EntireRow.Delete();
            }

}
        workbook.Save();
```